# trying to share pdf, using react-native-share v2.0.0

Tags: node.js, react-native, pdf

```
react-native application version:
react-native@0.61.2
react-navive-share@2.0.0
rn-fetch-blob@0.11.2
```

```
server with version:
html-pdf@2.2.0
```

i'm trying to make application that can create pdf by send data into nodejs.
and currently i already manage to create pdf from nodejs.

Now i already can share the pdf using whatsapp/gmail, but the file that i share have an alien language in it, i will share the picture below. (locally it works fine)

below are my code so far:

my api at nodejs :

```
router.route('/fetchpdf').get((req, res) => {
    const filePath = path.resolve(`${__dirname}/../../pdfquotation/${req.query.fileid}.pdf`);
    res.sendFile(filePath)
})
```

```
RNFetchBlob.config(configOptions)
  .fetch('GET', `http://domainName.com/api/pdf/fetchpdf?fileid=${fileid}`)
      .then(resp => {
          filePath = resp.path();
          return resp.readFile('base64');
      })
      .then(async base64Data => {
           base64Data = `data:${type};base64,` + base64Data;
           await SharePDF.open({ url: base64Data, title: 'title here' });
      });
```

and the result that i got from this are :
[image]

could someone pointing out, what should i do to fix this?

thanks

Comment: i dont have solution until now, maybe its because of the server linux. so for now i'm using react-native-html-to-pdf, and everything works fine